# Zero a row in a 2D array if the number zero exists in it

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write something that will get an MxN 2D array, go over each row and search for the number 0. If the number zero is present in that row, the whole row will be set to 0's.

So for example, this:

```java
int[][] arr ={{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0},
              {2, 36, 1, 2, 1, 6},
              {0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 5},
              {4, 4, 4, 225, 3, 4},
              {1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1}};
```

Will turn into this:

```java
int[][] arr ={{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
              {2, 36, 1, 2, 1, 6},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
              {4, 4, 4, 225, 3, 4},
              {1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1}};
```

I haven't made much progress. All my attempts at setting the row to zero either didn't work or zeroed out everything in the array.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TwoDarr { 
    public static void ZeroNum(int[][] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                        ???
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            int[][] arr ={{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0},
                            {2, 36, 1, 2, 1, 6},
                            {0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 5},
                            {4, 4, 4, 225, 3, 4},
                            {1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1}};
        ZeroNum(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
        }
        }
    }
```

Any help on the matter would be great,
Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly did you try? the simple `arr[i] = new int[arr[i].length]];` should work

Comment: @UnholySheep That indeed worked! I guess it comes down to me not knowing enough basics. How to I break down the line of code you sent here?

Comment: It simply replaces the array with a new array (of the same length), with the default value of `int` being 0. Alternatively you might consider using `Arrays.fill`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)

Comment: @UnholySheep If you could answer the post I'll gladly mark it as resolved, I literally just added your line of code inside the nested loop, after the if. Much appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Arrays.fill` to fill the row with `0`s. Note that a 2-D array in Java is an array of 1-D arrays.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr ={{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0},
                  {2, 36, 1, 2, 1, 6},
                  {0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 5},
                  {4, 4, 4, 225, 3, 4},
                  {1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1 } };
        for (int[] row : arr) {
            for (int col : row) {
                if (col == 0) {
                    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int[] row : arr) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 36, 1, 2, 1, 6]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 4, 4, 225, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1]
```

As given below, you can achieve it without using the enhanced for loop but I suggest you use the cleaner solution given above:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr ={{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0},
                  {2, 36, 1, 2, 1, 6},
                  {0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 5},
                  {4, 4, 4, 225, 3, 4},
                  {1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1 } };
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
                if(arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    arr[i] = new int[arr[i].length];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int[] row : arr) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }
}
```

This alternative solution will work only as long as the elements have to be changed to 0 (which is the default value of an `int`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any difference between using the `Arrays.fill` method as opposed to `arr[i] = new int[arr[i].length];`?

Comment: You are most welcome. I've updated my answer which clarifies it. Feel free to comment in case you need any further help.

Comment: @Socowi - Great suggestion! I've updated the answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr2d ={{...}};
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2d.length; i++) {
        if (containsZero(arr2d[i])) {
            arr2d[i] = new int[arr2d[i].length]]
        }
    }
}

public static boolean containsZero(int []arr) {
    for (int n : arr) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'm wondering if your approach gives better performance, run-time/num of steps wise?

Comment: The performance is the same of the other answer. The only difference is that I'm splitting the code in two methods here, so that containsZero is reusable. If you want to improve the performance you should not use arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr ={{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0},
                {2, 36, 1, 2, 1, 6},
                {0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 5},
                {4, 4, 4, 225, 3, 4},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1 } };

      for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
              if(arr[i][j] == 0) {
                 arr[i]=new int[arr[i].length];
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      for (int[] row : arr) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
      }


    }
```